# Responsive Image circle for rectangle img tag?

Tags: html, css, image

This is the code that I have that only applies to the background image. I wanted the effect to be the same for the image tag in the html.

What I wanted is

```
<div class="pic">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

This is the actual code. Working [codepen](http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/yYyMeW).

HTML

```
<div class="pic"></div>
```

CSS

```
.pic {
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Q3DVhY0.jpg") no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  background-size: cover;
 display: block;
  background-position: center;
}
.pic:before{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 100%;  /* initial ratio of 1:1*/
}
```

How do I apply this effect to the image tag in html? I tried to do research on that but I couldn't find anything... I know that it's easier if the image was square but I wanted the effect to be applied to rectangle images with just html and css, no javascript.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/Lmh3nt6p/1/

```
.pic > img{ 
  position: relative;  
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 200px; 
}
```

Here is your circle lol! http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/Lmh3nt6p/5/

Comment: it's in oval, I want it to be in perfect circle.

Comment: Then make it a circle lol, you asked how to use the `img` inside your `div` so i showed you. If you want it to be a circle, ask another question.

Comment: @KristinaBressler I made it a circle for you

Comment: That's what I'm essentially asking in the question. I tried to edit it so that it'll be responsive and yet stay in circle. but no matter what I did, it won't work! It has something to do with the height...i think? This is my attempt: http://codepen.io/kikibres/pen/avzJQJ. The background properties only works on the background image.

Comment: @KristinaBressler Then update your question for the answer you are looking for! If the edges are going to be cropped off anyways, why not just make your img square?

Comment: I don't see why I need to update? As you can see, the background image is rectangle and I mentioned that. It's in perfect circle and I mentioned this. I just want to know how I can apply the effect to image tag in html...

Comment: @KristinaBressler it's ok, I will flag to delete for not being clear on your question. We will let SO handle it from here.

Comment: what is SO? What do they do?

Comment: SO stands for Stack Overflow, I referred to SO as a community. When something gets flagged it gets voted on to see if it should be removed or not. As your question sits, it is not clear on what you want, the requirements you put in the comments should be moved to your original question.